# How to get the filename of file downloaded by wget

Tags: bash, wget

I am using the following to download a file using wget only if it has changed since its last download.

```
wget --directory-prefix="$DIR" --content-disposition --timestamping "$URL"
```

I want wget to name the file as appropriate (the URL is passed into my script so I do not know what it might be) and I want to use --timestamping, so I cannot use --output-document.

How can I determine the file name used?

I thought I could search in $DIR for the most recent file, but that wouldn't work if there are multiple files in that directory (there could be) and the file is already the latest one determined using timestamping.

Comment: Create an empty temp dir, download the file into that. Then you'll have only ONE file to worry about, and can move it elsewhere. Otherwise you're stucking analyzing $URL and hoping it contains the filename, and if it's something like `example.com?fileID=xxx`, then you'd have to look at the http response headers and parse out the filename from the content-disposition header.

Comment: You'll got the same if check for last modified file in a given directory, assuming that no more processes are writing to it. It's not necessary, but easier, to use a custom path.

Answer (score 0):

If the processing of `Content-Disposition` isn't important (since I'm not sure curl does it) then you can use `curl` for this instead.

```
outfile=$DIR/foo
curl -z "$outfile" -o "$outfile" --remote-time "$URL"
```

But be careful not to use a filename that `curl` might parse as a date (the `-z` flag is stupid that way).